# Why such links are valid in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I use Wordpress for my website. There are some categories with their own posts. For example for category named "mycat" Wordpress generates link http://mysite.com/topics/mycat
I've found if I open page with url something like http://mysite.com/topics/something/blahblahblah/mycat the same page are opened! How can I redirect this urls to 404 page?

Answer (score 0):

That is because wordpress by default takes the last value as the input parameter after the "topic" keyword. That is why it is returning the same page. For example if you enter http://mysite.com/topics/something/mycat/lkjasdklfj Now that will show you an 404 error.

Comment: Thanks!Do you know how can I change this default rule?

Comment: check in wp-includes/query.php file